# Return the current month salary and previous month salary in a same table

Tags: sql-server, plsql, peoplesoft

I have a task to prepare a report generated from a run control page and retrieve the current month salary and previous month salary. In that page, the user will choose the `cal_id` they want for example in this case the user choose `cal id` = `FEB`. Assume the table as below named `table_salary`:

```
emplid | cal_id | salary | pymt_date
101    | JAN    | 10000  | 2018-01-01
101    | FEB    | 15000  | 2018-02-01
```

And my expected output is

```
emplid | cur_sal| prev_sal 
101    | 15000  | 10000
```

What I have done so far is like below

```
SELECT 
    A.EMPLID, A.SALARY AS CUR_SAL, B.SALARY AS PREV_SAL
FROM  
    TABLE_SALARY A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    TABLE_SALARY B ON A.EMPLID AND B.EMPLID
                   AND A.CAL_ID = B.CAL_ID
                   AND B.PYMT_DT = (SELECT MAX(B1.PYMT_DT)
                                    FROM TABLE_SALARY B1
                                    WHERE B1.EMPLID = B.EMPLID
                                      AND B1.PYMT_DT >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, B.PYMT_DT) - 1, 0)
                                      AND B1.PYMT_DT < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, PYMT_DT), 0))
```

But above SQL didn't return the expected output.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve my expected output?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @saarrrr cool, this is what i looking for. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: @marc_s okay sir, thank you for you comment. I'll take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

Use a window function to retrieve the previous row in a sorted set. I think this should work.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    EMPLID, SALARY AS CUR_SAL, LEAD(SALARY, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY PYMT_DT DESC) AS PREV_SAL
FROM
    TABLE_SALARY
ORDER BY
    PYMT_DT DESC
```

Comment: It should be `LAG(...)  OVER (ORDER BY PYMT_DT )` otherwise LAG will return the *next* value

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this
Use Lead instead of Lag

```
Create table #t ( id int identity (1,1), Empid int , Month varchar
(10), Salary int, Paymentdate date )


insert into #t (Empid ,Month,Salary,Paymentdate) Select
'1','Jan',1000, '2018-01-01'

insert into #t (Empid ,Month,Salary,Paymentdate) Select
'1','Feb',1500, '2018-02-01'

Select * from #t

SELECT TOP 1
    Empid, SALARY AS CUR_SAL, Lead(SALARY, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY PaymentDate DESC) AS PREV_SAL FROM
    #t ORDER BY
    Paymentdate DESC




SELECT TOP 1
    Empid, SALARY AS CUR_SAL, LAG(SALARY, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY PaymentDate DESC) AS PREV_SAL FROM
    #t ORDER BY
    Paymentdate DESC
```

Comment: hi, function `LAG()` is working fine if the previous row is from the same calendar type. What if I have different calendar type for emplid `101` i.e. `Jan(10000)`,`OffCycle Jan(200)`,` Feb(15000)` *salary in bracket. If I use `LAG()` cal_id Feb will take value from `OffCycle(200)` as the previous month salary instead of `Jan(10000)`. How you can help on this?